# AttatchInterrupt Constantly interrupts

Tags: arduino

I am a new to electronics. I am trying to setup the radio control for the arduino. I hooked up the Reciever's Channel 1 to the Arduino Mega 2560's Digital pin 2, Reciever Vin to Arduino 5V, and Ground to Ard Ground. Here is my Source Code.

```
void setup() {
        Serial.begin(9600);
        attachInterrupt(0 , blink, CHANGE);
     }

void loop() {
   Serial.println("I AM IN THE LOOP");        

}


void blink()
{

     Serial.println("I AM IN THE INTERRUPT");  
}
```

I tried using other interrupt pins,3.3 V instead of 5 and also tried  Arduino Uno and differnt kinds of Interrupt Values like RISING, LOW and FALLING but it constantly prints " I AM IN THE INTERRUPT" without me touching the transmitter. Any suggestions.

[UPDATE]
After a great deal of discussion on 
http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=184283.0
I came to this conclusion. Radio generates PWM signal  .. If you have an interrupt pin connected to a channel. It will interrupt regardless of what you do because it is constantly generating a PWM. So I am leaning towards interrupt is not a good idea for radio control.

Comment: What kind of receiver are you using? Some of the cheap OOK receiver modules will receive junk the whole time there's not a carrier.

Comment: Yes it is a hobbyking T6A V2 6 channel reciever 30 dollar kit.

Comment: I don't know if this is the right way to check ,, But when I check the data line of the reciever, the Voltage is 0.27 constant, On change of the transmitter handle the voltagegoes to 0.32/ 0.22. So I don't think there is any junk. Or what do you think? – Rabin 52 mins ago

Comment: If I'm not mistaken - this is a model aircraft remote. The receiver drives "servos" directly - it is not a logic on/off output. It provides a PWM type output that controls a servo with a varying frequency pulse stream. You would have to decipher the output as such - not by sampling for logical on/off.

Comment: Yes you are correct.

Comment: Actually, interrupt is fine - it's just that you can't deduce much from the *fact* of the interrupt, but rather must measure the *timing* between the start and end of the pulse, something interrupts can  help with.  Or you can use a hardware timer to take the measurement - though you may then use either an interrupt or poling to discover that a measurement has been taken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've determined that kind of receiver will have a PWM output to control a servo, the Wikipedia [Servo Control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Servo_control) article has some good information about it. If you wanted to use it anyway the normal neutral position will be 1.5mS so you could use something like the following code that uses the [pulseIn](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/pulseIn) function to treat a pulse of 1.75mS or longer as being on:

```
#define MY_PIN 0

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(MY_PIN, INPUT);
}

void loop() {
   if (pulseIn(MY_PIN, HIGH) >= 1750)
      Serial.println("TX on");        
}
```

Note that the typical period between pulses is 20mS so your code will be stalled in `pulseIn` for around that period. If that's a problem you could go back to using the interrupt and set it for `CHANGE` and keep track of the time between when the line goes high and low again. It would be something like the following untested code:

```
#define MY_PIN 0 // Make sure this matches the interrupt line
unsigned long start_micros = 0;
unsigned long last_duration = 0;

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(MY_PIN, INPUT);
    attachInterrupt(0 , PWM_handler, CHANGE);
}

void loop() {
   if (last_duration >= 1750)
      Serial.println("TX on");        
}

void PWM_hander()
{
    if (digitalRead(MY_PIN) == HIGH)
        start_micros = micros();
    else
        last_duration = micros() - start_micros;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure if the receiver has an open collector output or not, but it is quite likely. I believe the interrupt pin is pin 2. Add a `pinMode( 2 , INPUT_PULLUP );` before the `attachInterrupt`.

Also your interrupt routine may be a bit long (in duration). It is better to just flash LED on pin 13 or set a flag in the interrupt routine then do some smart stuff with that flag in the main loop.

You may want to check with an oscilloscope if the LED is constantly on or not.

Comment: I tried the LED with the pinMode( 2 , INPUT_PULLUP ); The LED constantly flashes..  That means its still going in the interrupt

Comment: Does the flashing stop if you disconnect pin 2?

Comment: Yes the flashing stops when I turn off my transmitter or disconnct pin 2

Comment: Then it seems an issue with the receiver, not with Arduino.